# wrapping node-memcached with deferred.promisify error

Tags: node.js, memcached

I am trying to wrap the node-memcached api with deferred's promisify in order to simplify my nested callbacks.

When I try to call the promisified function I just get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'namespace' of undefined".

```
Memcached = require('memcached');
var memcache = new Memcached('localhost:11211');
var add = deferred.promisify(memcache.add);

add('myKey', 'myVal', 0)(function(result) {
    ...
});
```

I can't seem to find anyone else trying to wrap node-memcached, or getting my same error.  Any insight into what may be going wrong?  Or maybe even a push into a better direction if this is imperfect?

Thanks!

EDIT::

Just wanted to response that I found the best solution I could for now by doing some digging.

It seems that deferred.promisify calls the passed function with its own scope (this), instead of the context of the function that is passed in.

Using my own promisfy function appears to fix the issue (idea from http://howtonode.org/promises):

```
function promisify(fn, context) {
    return function() {
        var def = deferred();
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        args.push(function(err, val) {
            if (err !== null) {
                return def.reject(new Error(err));
            }
            return def.resolve(val);
        });

        fn.apply(context, args);
        return def.promise;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When promisify instances members you should bind it to this instance like:

```
Memcached = require('memcached');
var memcache = new Memcached('localhost:11211');
var add = deferred.promisify(memcache.add.bind( memcache ) );

add('myKey', 'myVal', 0)(function(result) {
    ...
});
```