# Memcached: How to remove all the keys

Tags: node.js, memcached, memcached-promisify

I'm newbie with memcached. I'm making a development using node with the library *memcached-promisify* and I would like to know how can I remove all the keys saved in the caché.

I believed that with the method flush() would be enought but ... This method doesn't exists!!!

[image]

How can I do that? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753003/wrapping-node-memcached-with-deferred-promisify-error

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but it doesn't work me!!! :(